# Components not linking between Delphi XE3 and Fast Report 4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, fastreport

I am trying to print an array in FastReport 4. I found the tutorial on their official page and tried to put it to use. I added a `TfrxUserDataSet` component and a `MasterData` in the report. However, I cannot link those two. `MasterData` does not see my `TfrxUserDataSet` component.

What am I doing wrong? The compiled demo didn't help me, because I don't have the C language installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Report>Data... in Report Designer and check your TfrxUserDataSet there.